# Call a class from another script

Tags: python, selenium, class

I have found a peace of code I can use in my own script, I am not quite sure how the code all works, but it does :-), but as a newbee I dont know how to call it, it look like this:

```
"""
This script uses a simplified version of the one here:
https://snipt.net/restrada/python-selenium-workaround-for-full-page-screenshot-using-chromedriver-2x/

It contains the *crucial* correction added in the comments by Jason Coutu.
"""

import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest
import time
import util
from random import randint


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Demonstration: Get Chrome to generate fullscreen screenshot """

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_fullpage_screenshot(self):
        ''' Generate document-height screenshot '''

        url = "https://www.(a login page)

        # Login on Stockopedia
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('XXXXXXXXXXXXX')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('XXXXXXXXXXXXX')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('auth_submit').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        # Indsæt tickerkode
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('searchQuery').send_keys(var1, Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('searchQuery').send_keys('', Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(randint(10, 60))

        util.fullpage_screenshot(self.driver, "test.jpg")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(argv=[sys.argv[0]])
```

Can anybody help me, so I can call it from another script with variable **var1** as a argument

I have now add the script that call the Class, the call is between the 2 row´s of stars *. 
But as I see it, not even an instance of the class is created, what do I do wrong ?

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import logging
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pickle
import requests
import re
import test
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import time

yf.pdr_override

#  ticker_index indeholder: stien til det website den skal hente tickerkoderne,
# klassenavnet på den tabel tickerkoderne i, nummer på den kolonne i tabellen
# tickerkoderne ligger i, og navnet på den fil programmet skal ligge
# tickerkoderne i
# ticker_indexes = [['dk_large_cap', 'http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/index/index_info?Instrument=SE0001776667',
#                   'tablesorter tablesorter-default', 1, 'dk_large_cap_tickers.pickle']]
ticker_indexes = [['c25', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMX_Copenhagen_25',
                   'wikitable sortable', 2, 'c25_tickers.pickle'],
                  ['dax', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAX',
                   'wikitable sortable', 3, 'dax_tickers.pickle'],
                  ['sto30', 'https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMXS30',
                  'wikitable sortable', 2, 'sto30_tickers.pickle'],
                  ['obx25', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBX_Index',
                   'wikitable sortable', 2, 'obx25_tickers.pickle'],
                  ['nasdaq100', 'https://www.cnbc.com/nasdaq-100/',
                   'data quoteTable', 0, 'nasdaq100.pickle']]


logging.basicConfig(filename='Share prices logfile.log', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')


def save_index_tickers(indexname, tickerpath, table_class_id, tickercol,
                       tickerlist):
    try:
        resp = requests.get(tickerpath)
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
        table = soup.find('table', {'class': table_class_id})
        tickers = []
        for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
            ticker = row.findAll('td')[tickercol].text.replace('.', '-')
            ticker = ticker.strip('\n')
            if (indexname == 'sto30') or (indexname == 'obx25'):
                ticker = ticker[1:]
            tickers.append(ticker)
            print(ticker)

        with open('C:\\Users\\Johnn\\Desktop\\FA Sheet\\pickle/' + tickerlist, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(tickers, f)
        logging.info(str(indexname) + ' ' + str(tickerlist) + ' OK')
        return tickers
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(str(indexname) + str(tickerlist) + str(e))


# save__screendump
def get_scrdump_from_stop(indexname, tickerpath, table_class_id, tickercol,
                          tickerlist, reload=False):
    try:
        if reload:
            logging.info('RELOAD ' + str(indexname) + str(tickerlist))
            tickers = save_index_tickers(indexname, tickerpath, table_class_id,
                                         tickercol, tickerlist)
        else:
            with open('C:\\Users\\Johnn\\Desktop\\FA Sheet\\pickle/' + tickerlist, "rb") as f:
                tickers = pickle.load(f)
            if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\Johnn\\Desktop\\FA Sheet\\Sheet'):
                os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\Johnn\\Desktop\\FA Sheet\\Sheet')
# ******************************************************************************
        for ticker in tickers:
            obj = test.Test(var1)
            obj.setUp()
            obj.test_fullpage_screenshot()
            obj.tearDown()
#*******************************************************************************
        logging.info(str(indexname) + ' Sheet downloaded OK')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(str(indexname) + str(tickerlist) + str(e))



def main(ticker_indexes):

    for ticker_index in ticker_indexes:
        print('*****')
        print(ticker_index[0])
        print('*****')
        save_index_tickers(ticker_index[0], ticker_index[1], ticker_index[2],
                           ticker_index[3], ticker_index[4])

        get_scrdump_from_stop(ticker_index[0], ticker_index[1], ticker_index[2],
                              ticker_index[3], ticker_index[4])

    logging.info('Finished')


main(ticker_indexes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import your file as such

- ***If the importing class is in another dir.***

```
import dir1.dir2.filename
```

- ***if you are calling the class from a file created in the same dir***

```
import filename
```

To create an object of your file's class.

```
obj = filename.Test(var1)
```

Then the rest of the code will look like this.

```
obj.setUp()
obj.test_fullpage_screenshot()
obj.tearDown()
```

If you're wondering what self means in the code.

- To execute the function in the class, you need the first argument which is the own class object **self**.
- why we do this is so that you won't call the class like this, without instantiating the object.

```
filename.Test.setUp()
```

Comment: Thangs a lot, that almost solved it. :-) But how do I get access to the var1 in the line: self.driver.find_element_by_name('searchQuery').send_keys(var1, Keys.ENTER), do I have do do it in the Class line or in the def test_fullpage_screenshot(self): line

Comment: You can alter the class and try to print that argument name, where in this case the variable would be "unittest.TestCase"

Comment: I have now add the script that call the Class, the call is between the 2 row´s of stars *. But as I see it, not even an instance of the class is created, what do I do wrong ?

Comment: Sorry I don´t know what you mean by that

Comment: I have put it into the original questions, if it was that you was asking for

Comment: Please check the below.

1.) Believe your filename is test.py and it is present in the same dir as your now executing code. That is why you have used import test.
2.) You are calling the class like obj = test.Test(var1). But can you try calling the class without the variable in it? as obj = test.Test()
3.) are you importing the file correctly ? Can you share your error?

Comment: Hi again, Sorry for having been away for a while. 1: Yes 2: without a variable, it is working. 3: WARNING: c25c25_tickers.pickleno such test method in <class 'test.Test'>

Comment: So there is a chance that "unittest.TestCase" is a inherited class.

Comment: I am not quite sure of what that means, I know what Inherited Class means, But I am not so familier with Classes yet, so is there a work around for me in this case.

Comment: I guess not, you have to check if it has been inherited or not.

Comment: Thangs for trying, I have now found another example of a script that can make a screendump, and I vil try to get that to work :-)